# ActionScript 3 : Socket, amf, NetConnection, rtmp... Getting clear

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, sockets, amf, rtmp

Could someone help me understanding binary data transferring between flash client and server?
How do rtmp-servers work? How is video transferring between server and client? What's the difference between using Socket and NetConnection? Is rtmp-server just a socket server supporting amf serialization?

I'll be very happy, if someone explains me these aspects. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Socket** low level class to access network session, creates TCP connection, can send raw bytes or serialized objects.

**AMF** flash object encoded to binary data that can be transfered via network or saved to `SharedObject`. Only public fields or classes implementing `IExternalizable` are serialized. Mark them with meta tag `[RemoteClass(alias="com.foo.Bar")]`.

**NetConnection** many protocols connection (RTMP, RTMPT, RTMPE, and UDP based RTMPF), can send serialized objects via remote procedure calls

How **rtmp-server** works? Depends... opens port and listens for RTMP/TCP connection from client.

RTMP server offers remote **SharedObject**, recording audio/video **NetStream** published from client and receiveing remote procedure calls (netConnection.call(handler, ...params)) and can redirect your NetStream directly to other client/subscriber which is playing it.

reference:

- http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/Socket.html
- http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetConnection.html
- http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html
- http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html
- http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=metadata_3.html or http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html#registerClassAlias()